# arrows not updated when ordering open source projects in careers profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, sorting, open-source

When using the arrows on the right side to change the order of your open source projects the arrows are not updated properly. The first and last initially just have a down and up arrow respectively. When you reorder the projects so that one or both of them get another position you would expect the arrows to update to allow the former first to be moved both up and down while the new first should loose it's up arrow.

Currently this doesn't happen and the previous first keeps it only down arrow and the new first has both up and down arrows.

Comment: marked as no repro because this is not happening today, it's possible it was fixed and this post was not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has since been fixed, issue resolved.